# Ipsec site to site Vpn

Tags: vpn, ipsec

I need to communicate for three sites through vpn. For below scenario,

[image]

is possible to reach 10.33.209.xx/27 from 192.168.60.xx.

please give any idea to communicate in three segment.

Comment: You need to edit you question to include what make/models of network equipment and configurations you have, and what doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Hi Ron Maupin, there is fortinet firewalls, the configuration details are from spoke: .edit "Corp-Airtel"
        set interface "wan2"
        set mode aggressive
        set proposal 3des-sha1
        set remote-gw xxx.xx.xx.x
        set psksecret En
    next

edit "Corp-Airtel2"
        set keepalive enable
        set pfs disable
        set phase1name "Corp-Airtel"
        set proposal 3des-sha1
        set dst-subnet 10.200.0.0 255.255.0.0
        set src-subnet 192.168.60.0 255.255.255.0

Comment: 10.200.2.xx firewall config:edit "Spoke"
        set interface "wan2"
        set mode aggressive
        set proposal 3des-sha1
        set remote-gw xxx.xx.xx.x
        set psksecret En
    next

edit "Spoke-Phase2"
        set keepalive enable
        set pfs disable
        set phase1name "Corp-Airtel"
        set proposal 3des-sha1
        set dst-subnet 192.168.60.0 255.255.255.0
        set src-subnet 10.200.0.0 255.255.0.0

Comment: Now i i will reach the server (10.33.209.xx) from 192.168.60.xx via 10.200.2.xx.....   Did you understand my issue

Comment: we can communicate 10.33.209.xx to 10.200.2.xx

Comment: You need to edit your question to provide the details, and you should include the configurations. Without the configurations, we can't see where you may have gone wrong. It may be as simple as setting static routes to the far ends on each end.

Comment: Looks like a hub and spoke topology with the 10.200.2.0/24 network being the hub.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is a so called hub and spoke configuration, if you are using Fortigate appliances, then you can follow this documentation.

http://cookbook.fortinet.com/hub-and-spoke-vpn-using-quick-mode-selectors/

http://docs-legacy.fortinet.com/fos50hlp/50/index.html#page/FortiOS%205.0%20Help/hub-and-spoke.115.01.html

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, I just allowed the policy on each zone after that its working.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have set up the VPNs in interface mode (a.k.a. route-based), you need 2 things for this to work:

1- two routes to the other 2 networks
2- policies to allow the traffic

Let's call the 3 sites A,B,C and the firewall FGT.

If A can ping B, and B can ping C then you already have a route to network B in FGT A, and a route to network C in FGT B. You also have return routes in place, on FGT B to network A and network C.
Reversing the traffic: if you can ping from B to A, and from C to B then you have 2 policies on each FGT.

The key point for the necessary additions to your routes and policies to enable traffic from A to C is that the FGTs will drop traffic from "unknown" sources, that is, from networks they don't have a route to.

FGT A doesn't "know" about network C, and vice versa. So you need an additional route on FGT A to network C pointing to the tunnel interface to FGT B (the only tunnel interface here), and also one more route on FGT C to network A pointing to the (only) tunnel interface.

Then you have to add network C to both policies on FGT A (as destination and as source, respectively). The same applies to FGT C, allowing network A in the policies.

This does sound like a lot of effort for a WAN network with only 3 nodes. Having 4, 5,... nodes in between creates a substantial amount of configuration needs UNLESS you design your networks in a suitable manner.

If all networks behind the firewalls could be supernetted then policies and routes only have to be created once. Example: create networks A,B,C as 10.121.1.0/24, 10.121.2.0/24, 10.121.3.0/24. The only route needed on any FGT would be 10.121.0.0/16, and in the only 2 policies needed on any FGT you would have one destination 10.121.0.0/16 and one source 10.121.0.0/16. That's how hub-and-spoke VPNs are set up ideally.

Answer (score 0):

You should configure a full mesh VPN so that spoke to spoke traffic does not have to hairpin the main site.  In other words, configure a VPN between the branch sites.